# How to call UpdateCommand from button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am developing functionality of certain pages of my Q & A website to have full edit/delete functionality.

Here is the process:
1. The user clicks a link from a Datasource hyperlink on one page and it transfers the QuestionID they clicked to another page that populates two RadGrids. These RadGrids are Questions and Answers.
2. The Questions grid populates the question the user clicked, and the Answers grid populates all Answers that share the same QuestionID as the Questions table.
3. The user can then click "Edit" in the Answer RadGrid which in turn populates a RadTextBox with the stored name of the person who submitted that answer, and also populates a RadEditor with their answer. Another function to note is that when the user clicks the "Edit" button, it hides a Submit button (this button has a SQL Insert) and makes a "Update" button (this button has a SQL Update).

The issue that I ran into is that I had to make changes to the Update button as my query was updating all Answers associated with that QuestionID, i.e. bad SQL programming. To counteract this, I created an UpdateCommand event which gets the AnswerID instead of the QuestionID.

My question is how do I call that UpdateCommand event from the "Update" button?

This is my ItemCommand event:

```
protected void RadGrid2_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{  // This populates RadTextBox1 and RadEditor
     switch (e.CommandName)
     {
          case RadGrid.EditCommandName:
               e.Canceled = true;
               e.Item.Selected = true;
               e.Item.Edit = true;
               RadTextBox1.Text = (e.Item as GridDataItem)["AnsweredBy"].Text;
               RadEditor.Content = (e.Item as GridDataItem)["Answer(s)"].Text;
               break;
          case RadGrid.UpdateCommandName:
               SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters.Add("Answered By", RadTextBox1.Text);
               SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters.Add("Answer(s)", RadEditor.Content);
               break;
          default:
               break;                  
      }
      RadButton1.Visible = false;
      RadButton2.Visible = true;
 }
```

Here is my UpdateCommandEvent:

```
protected void RadGrid2_UpdateCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{  // This performs the SQL Update
     String connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

     string answerid = e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["AnswerID"].ToString();

     using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
     {
          conn.Open();
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Answers SET Answer_Name = @prmAnswer_Name, Answer = @prmAnswer, TimeAdded = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE AnswerID = " + answerid, conn);
          cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@prmAnswer_Name", RadTextBox1.Text));
          cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@prmAnswer", RadEditor.Text));
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          conn.Close();
      }
}
```

And lastly, here is my ButtonClick event:

```
protected void RadButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // How do I call the UpdateCommand event?
}
```

I should also note that calling RadGrid2_UpdateCommand(sender, e); does not work as it cannot convert from EventArgs to GridCommandEventArgs.

Here is RadGrid2:

```
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid2"
                runat="server" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
                GroupPanelPosition="Top" 
                OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid2_NeedDataSource" 
                OnDeleteCommand="RadGrid2_DeleteCommand" 
                OnUpdateCommand="RadGrid2_UpdateCommand" 
                OnItemCommand="RadGrid2_ItemCommand">        
                <MasterTableView DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="AnswerID, Answer(s), Answered By">
                    <Columns>
                        <telerik:GridButtonColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" CommandName="Edit" HeaderText="Edit" Text="Edit" UniqueName="Edit" />
                        <telerik:GridButtonColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" HeaderText="Delete" ConfirmText="Are you sure you want to delete the selected row?" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="AnswerID" FilterControlAltText="Filter AnswerID column" HeaderText="AnswerID" SortExpression="AnswerID" ReadOnly="true" Visible="false" UniqueName="AnswerID" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Answer(s)" FilterControlAltText="Filter Answer(s) column" HeaderText="Answer(s)" SortExpression="Answer(s)" UniqueName="Answer(s)" />
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Answered By" FilterControlAltText="Filter Answered By column" HeaderText="Answered By" SortExpression="AnsweredBy" UniqueName="AnsweredBy" />
           </Columns>
     </MasterTableView>
     <HeaderStyle BorderStyle="Outset" Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Comment: Make a separate function that does the updating and call it from `UpdateCommand` and `Click`

Comment: That is my update command event which I already have already above.  Calling it is the issue I am having.

Comment: Ah, I see.. Can you post your code-behind for `RadGrid2`?

Comment: I currently do not have any code-behind for RadGrid2 but I updated my original post with the ASP.

Comment: [CurrentRow](http://www.telerik.com/forums/radgridview-selected-index) would be useful for getting the selected row index. Also, with your `Update` button being outside of the `RadGrid`, could the user alter more than one row at a time? If so, your `button` code would need to run a loop instead of calling `UpdateCommand`.

Comment: No the user cannot alter more than one row at time, the edit feature will move that selected row into the RadEditor.  CurrentRow is not useful either as I have the UpdateCommand function that finds the ID for me.

Comment: What about adding this to your `Click` event: `GridCommandEventArgs args = new GridCommandEventArgs(); args.CommandName = "Update"; RadGrid2_UpdateCommand(sender, args);` You'll have to add more than just `CommandName` to `args` - maybe `ItemIndex`, but it might get you started.

Comment: I will test/research this for a while and then come back if I have any more questions.  Thank you for the help!